# Migrating a database full with data from MSSQL to MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, data-migration

I have a database filled with data from a MSSQL Windows-1253 and wanted to pass in a normal opencart database (UTF-8).
With the following code all English character pass ok but Greek characters inside come out like that ÄÁ×ÔÕËÉÄÉ

Any advise how to pass correct the data from one database to the other?

```
<? header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    include("config.php");
    $db1 = mysql_connect(DB_HOSTNAME, 'dbuser', 'dbpass');
    mysql_select_db('dbname', $db1) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_query( "SET NAMES utf8", $db1);
    mysql_query( "SET CHARACTER SET utf8", $db1);
    mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8', $db1);
    mysql_query('SET names=utf8', $db1);
    mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8', $db1);
    mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8', $db1);
    mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8', $db1);
    mysql_query('SET collation_connection=utf8_general_ci', $db1);
    mysql_set_charset('utf8',$db1);

    $db2 = mysql_connect(DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
    mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE, $db2) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_query( "SET NAMES utf8", $db2);
    mysql_query( "SET CHARACTER SET utf8", $db2);
    mysql_set_charset('utf8',$db2);

    //Update Categories
    $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM prdcategories", $db1) or die(mysql_error());
    $i = 0;
    echo "<h2>Updating categories</h2>";
echo "<ul>";
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM prdtypes WHERE id ='".$r['id']."'", $db1) or die(mysql_error());
    $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

    $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM category_description WHERE name='".$r['en']."'", $db2) or die(mysql_error());
    if(mysql_num_rows($check) == '0') {
        echo "<li><font color='blue'>Importing category <b>".$r['en']."</b>!</font>";
        if($i < 9) { $top = '1'; } else { $top = '0'; }
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO category VALUES ('', '', '0', $top, '1', '0', '1', NOW(), NOW())", $db2) or die(mysql_error());
        $id = mysql_insert_id();

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO category_description VALUES ($id, '1', '".$r['en']."', '', '', '')", $db2) or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO category_description VALUES ($id, '2', '".$r['el']."', '', '', '')", $db2) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: I think you need to look at [mb_convert_encoding() in the PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php)

Comment: Its look interesting, yes possibly that can help me, i try to see it. Thank you.